# xamarin navigation - how to normally implement navigation between login and masterdetailpage

Tags: xamarin, navigation, master-detail

So, how do you normally implement navigation between login page and `masterdetailpage`.?

I tried few implementation and not really what I am looking for.

So basically, when the login is successful, the`masterdetailpage` should be the root navigation so if we go back /or pop, we would need to go out of the app. But at the moment, it goes back to the login page.

I tried..

using `NavigationPage` and `InsertPageBefore` the `mainpage` and pop so it is in the root page, but there is a catch because of the navigation tab showing on both `loginpage` and `masterdetailpage` (one tab layer for `navigationpage` and one extra layer of tab for master page in `masterdetailpage`)

I tried..

just instantiating the `App.MainPage` as `new loginPage()` without wrapping in `NavigationPage`, but I could not find a way to open `masterdetailpage`

Any help and direction is appreciated cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not to add LoginPage to Navigation.

You should

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

after login is ok you should

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new MyMasterDetailPage();
```

Comment: does this change the root? which means that in the login page if I create a mainLogin page that navigate to either login page or registration page, can I use `new NavigationPage` then later use `Application.Current.MainPage = new MyMasterDetailPage();`?

Comment: Of course. I think one time you have "closed" your "login situation", you have to set your MainPage. In this way you don't return to LoginPage if you press BackButton